Where is the Manger Name Pulled From ? In SharePoint Designer Workflow, "Lookup manager for an user". action
I have a SharePoint 2016 list with a Person/Group Column and a SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow running. The function of the workflow is to find the manager of the user name entered under the person/group column. When the workflow runs, it's retrieving the value of Manager's Name, but can anyone help on where's this Manager Name being pulled from.? I have checked the SharePoint 2016 - User Profiles, it doesn't seem to pull from there.
I'm using this action on SPD2010 WF.
This is my WorkFlow.

